# How to setup Global vnet peering in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vnet

I have two vnets setup in azure, one in UK South and one in UK West.  I have a single VM setup in each region and attached to the respective vnet.

I have peered the two vnets, using the peerings option in the blades on the azure portal.  However I am still unable to ping one VM from the the other.

I have NOT setup any Gateways as I understand this is not needed and I can see form the Effective Routes on the Network Interface for each VM that the VNetGlobalPeering has been established

Has anyone managed to get this working? Or can someone point me the the direction of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a gateway for this to work. what you need is to peer them and check the `Configure virtual network access settings` checkbox and configure your OS level firewall rules to allow the traffic.

Also, make sure NSG are not explicitly blocking that traffic

ps. you can follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal

Comment: Thanks. The link helped.  Didnt realize Windows firewall was blocking ICMP so ping wasnt working.